# Consistently deploying Cloudfunction with PubSub and Google Scheduler

Tags: continuous-integration, terraform, gcloud, continuous-deployment

I am trying to automatize deployment of three modules: Cloud Function which is invoked via PubSub subscription from Cloud Scheduler. Currently I have a following script, which uses gcloud command:

```
    gcloud beta pubsub topics create $SCHEDULE_NAME || echo "Topic $SCHEDULE_NAME already created."
    gcloud beta functions deploy $SCHEDULE_NAME
      --region $CLOUD_REGION
      --memory 128MB
      --runtime nodejs10
      --entry-point $ENTRY_POINT
      --trigger-topic $SCHEDULE_NAME
      --vpc-connector cloud-function-connector
    # gcloud scheduler jobs delete $JOB_NAME # does not work as it needs YES non-interactively
    gcloud scheduler jobs create pubsub $SCHEDULE_NAME --message-body='RUN' --topic=$SCHEDULE_NAME --schedule='27 2 * * *' --time-zone='Europe/London' || true
```

This works, however I am not sure whether this is the most correct way to do this. For instance, there is no way to just update the job if it already exists. I was considering `terraform`, but I am not sure it is useful just for deploying these three small modules. I discovered also `serverless` tool, however it seems it can only deploy cloud function, but not schedulers and pubsub topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach is straightforward and fine.

Does Terraform provide the job update capability? If so, you'll likely find that it simply deletes and then (re)creates the job. I think this approach (delete-then-recreate) to updating jobs is fine too and seems to provide more control; you can check whether the schedule is about to fire before|after updating it.

Google provides [Deployment Manager](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager) as a Google-Cloud-specific deployment tool. In my experience, it's primary benefit is that it's server-side but, ultimately, you're just automating the same APIs that you're using with `gcloud`.

If you want to learn a tool to manage your infrastructure as code, I'd recommend Terraform over Deployment Manager.

#### Update

The Scheduler API supports 'patching' jobs:

https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.jobs/patch

And this mechanism is supported by `gcloud`:

```sh
gcloud alpha scheduler jobs update
```